# Transfer data from Cassandra to Postgressql

Tags: postgresql, cassandra

I would like to know it will have any solution

Problem :

I have Cassandra database for saving large scale data from other sources continuously. Application-based data are saving in postgressql. For functionality, I want to query all data from postgresql. so I would like to save Cassandra data consistently to postgressql database based on data coming in Cassandra.

Is it possible?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to save Cassandra data consistently to PostgreSQL database based on data coming in Cassandra.

There are no special utilities for this. You need to create your own service to gather data from Cassandra, process it and put results to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can use Change Data Capture (CDC) to copy the data from Cassandra to PostgreSQL as and when there is a change in Cassandra data. One option is to use Kafka Connect with appropriate coonectors.

Comment: @user3541485 refer to the confluent website for appropriate Kafka connectors and integration documentation